# How to Importing image from server and arrange it in a view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, nsurlconnection

I need to get array of images that have to call from server and arrange that in an order.But while executing below code i can't get it...Guidance please...

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

NSURL *url = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString: 
                                        @"http://images.wikia.com/marvelmovies/images/5/5e/The-hulk-2003.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/img/google_logo.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://addyosmani.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Google-doodle-of-Richard-007.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techcitement.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/apple-vs-google_2.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.andymangels.com/images/IronMan_9_wallpaper.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sequelnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/iphone_5.jpg"],Nil];

/*
int i=0;
int cord_x=0;
int cord_y=30;
int cont=0;

for (i = 0; i < [(NSArray*)url count]; i++) {
    cont=cont+1;
    if (cont > 3) {
        cord_x=0;
        cord_y=cord_y+110;
        cont=1;
    }*/

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)[(NSArray*)url objectAtIndex:index]]]; 

    //cord_x=cord_x+110;



UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f);

[button setImage:(UIImage*)[image objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return button;

}

//}
```

now i need to place button image and image from server...

Comment: do u checked those images on the browsers?

Comment: So wait, the images aren't showing up in the view, or are they NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int row = 0;
int column = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < url.count; ++i) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)   [(NSArray*)url objectAtIndex:i]]]; 

    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+16, row*90, 80, 80);
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = i; 
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    if (column == 2) {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    } else {
        column++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u tell me if i need to arrange individual image to individual imageview that i named as iv1,iv2,etc...

Comment: @DANY FOR THAT U HAVE TO SET THE FRAME SIZE OF EACH IMAGEVIEW. R U TYING TO CREATE ANY KIND OF IMAGE GALLARY?

Comment: :yes..but i'm creating like if we touches image it leads to buy that image product...

Comment: hey i had created image gallery of grid view. if u want more help than tell me.

Comment: yes i need...tks for ur help...now i edited the question pls chk it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220795/how-to-importing-image-from-server-and-arrange-it-in-a-view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13102/discussion-between-smartwork-and-dany)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use NSURLConnection to download images asynchronous which will make your UI much more responsive. Just setup separate connection for each image and update images on the buttons in delegate method - connectionDidFinishLoading. It will also help you to track downloading errors (e.g. timeouts etc.).
Here is a great example with downloads images for table - you can find there a lot of help for your case:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"www.xxx.com/imag.jpg",@"www.xxx.com/img1.jpg",nil];
for(int i=0; i<[arrayList count]; i++)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayList ObjetAtIndex:i]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:data];               // Here is your image
}
```

Comment: That is not working and i'm getting multiple warning and SIGNAL sigabart issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobiledevelopertips.com/images/logo-iphone-dev-tips.png"],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],Nil];


int i=0;
int cord_x=0;
int cord_y=30;
int cont=0;

for (i = 0; i < [(NSArray*)url count]; i++)
{
    cont=cont+1;
    if (cont > 3)
    {
        cord_x=0;
        cord_y=cord_y+110;
        cont=1;
    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)[(NSArray*)url objectAtIndex:i]]]; 
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cord_x, cord_y, 100, 100)];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    cord_x=cord_x+110;
}
```

Comment: Can u tell me if i need to arrange individual image to individual imageview that i named as iv1,iv2,etc...

Comment: thats not necessary, let me edit the code for you. just a sec

Comment: @Dany I edited the code, added some url in NSURL *url;  this will give you images in thumbnail view, you can set the tag of you imageview lik imageView.tag = i;