# NSURLConnection for multiple images

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I have to develop a code for following code :

1. set up an apache server on ur mac.
2. host about 200+ photos there. (each should be about 1 mb to 2 mb)
3. Right a Tab bar app with 4 tabs.
4. Tab 1 : Implement a UITableView that should display all ur hosted photos. Load the photos synchronously
5. Tab 2 : Implement a UITableView that should display all ur hosted photos. Load the photos asynchronously.

I have set up apache server from System Preferences under Sharing and created a tab bar now how to implement step 4 and 5. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on my answer here to get idea how to do your step 5 (Apple documentation provides great example with lazy image load into tableview):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268636/1033662

Comment: ok but i ve to inherit images from my apache server ...how to use that